# Anyone knows the shortcut for opening google chrome side search panel?

Tags: google-chrome, command, shortcut

[image]

Is there anyone familiar with the command to access the side search panel in Google Chrome? I've successfully activated it through chrome://flags, but I'm aware that there's supposed to be a direct keyboard shortcut for this function. I find it rather peculiar that there's a lack of information about this online.

Would anyone happen to know the precise command and the necessary prerequisites to trigger the side panel using a keyboard shortcut?

I appreciate your assistance.